# What is the origin of 'Gosh'?

Tags: etymology, minced-oaths

'Gosh' is a common substitute for the word 'God' in phrases such as 'Oh My Gosh' or 'By Gosh' or just 'Gosh'. Is this just a corruption of the word 'God' or does it have some other provenance? How long has it been in use?

[25nov2017] The usual secondary sources, *OED* and *Etymology Online*, don't seem to adequately answer the questions. For example, is 1757 the earliest date of use? What evidence suggests 'gosh' is a mispronunciation of 'god'?

Comment: No need of '*for*' at the end, I think.

Comment: @Kris [I don't think it hurts.](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/16/19365)

Comment: Any relation of @David Wallace? Sheer coincidence?

Comment: @Kris Me? Not that I know of. This is the only David Wallace I've ever heard of: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Wallace_(The_Office)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Wallace_(The_Office))

Comment: Check a dictionary: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gosh

Comment: Related: _[Is “honest to gosh” a popular and decent English idiom?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/63347/5822)_

Comment: What the heck??

Comment: @DoubleAA - what?  Are you forgetting the great Rugby football player from Ireland? (who is also no relation of mine)

Comment: @DoubleAA: I requested a reopening of this question on [meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/2668/5822). From the answer there, I gather you'll have better luck with reopening if you edit it to include the direction of your own research and specify which questions have not been answered by general reference resources.

Comment: U.S. newspaper (and newspaper cartoon) readers of a certain age will recall that Snuffy Smith's wife Loweezy frequently used the expression "Land o' Goshen" as an expletive indicating amazement, delight, or outrage. The _Lewiston [Maine] Sun-Journal_ has an [interesting item](https://www.sunjournal.com/2003/03/23/land-o-goshen-rarely-heard-today/) on that phrase, dated March 23, 2003, from the editors of Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary. Evidently, the euphemism "gosh" did **not** arise from the Biblical "land of Goshen."

Answer (score 12):

Etymonline has this on the word:

> **[gosh](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=gosh&allowed_in_frame=0)** 
>   1757, altered pronunciation of *God*. Probably from *by gosse* (mid-16c.).

but offers no additional information on *gosse* other than as a German word for *gutter* under the entry for *[gut](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=gut&allowed_in_frame=0)*.

Wikitonary's listing for *[gosse](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gosse)* also seems to hold no further clues.

Here's a clip of the earliest use in print from Barry's OED answer:

[image]

This is from a [1765 collection of Samuel Foote's plays](http://books.google.com/books?id=uK0_AAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false). This play, *The Author*, was originally published in 1757. He uses the phrase once again later in the same play:

[image]

**Edit:**

Just figured out that the *by gosse* mentioned at Etymonline is from *[Ralph Roister Doister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ralph_Roister_Doister)*, a comic play by Nicholas Udall generally regarded as the first comedy to be written in the English language. It was published c. 1567. Here is a [clip](http://books.google.com/books?id=NUQUAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43&dq=By%20gosse%20and%20for%20thy%20sake%20I%20defye%20hir%20in%20deede&source=bl&ots=vWvH1TBXM3&sig=5VBIdTPvGgP-q-ycBgmQNGh_8vo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=oJu5T_uLNuuEsgK4qZGLDA&ved=0CDwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=gosse&f=false) from the play reprinted in 1821:

[image]

Comment: The OED has Udall's *gosse* as it's only citation, and gives the year as "?1556". The prolegomena at the front of the book you found gives further information: in 1556, it was entered on the books of the stationers' company as a play about to be published and then it seems the bookseller cancelled it, "but there is litle doubt that it was printed shortly after".

Comment: The prolegomena reads 1566, not 1556. I think part of the confusion here is that the play was written and performed several years before it was published (according to my Wikipedia link above, though it lacks citation).

Comment: Oops, I misread those similar-looking dates to be the same. Yes, that makes sense. The OED has "a1556" for the citation date: this is Udall's year of death, so he must have written it before then! It then has "(?1566)" for the publication date: this tallies with the prolegomena.

Answer (score 10):

*Gosh* has **no** literal meaning. It's not supposed to.

It's a ***[Euphemism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphemism)***, which means it's a word that is used instead of a taboo word (in this case, as you suggest, the taboo word is *God*).

This is word magic, and the usual magic principle that requires correct pronunciation to effect magical results applies. (For example, in the case of [Sanskrit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanskrit), correct pronunciation of the Vedas was believed to be necessary for the preservation of the Universe, leading directly to the invention and development of a scientific phonetics by  Pāṇini)

Specifically, if you offend a Power by saying its name, or referring to something forbidden, you may be noticed and punished; so you avoid that by saying something similar enough to be recognized by us humans who are in on the joke, which the Power nevertheless might not notice. Gods, as Terry Pratchett points out, don't have to be very smart or observant, when they have humans to do it for them.

The Greeks, who invented the term *euphemism* (from *eu-* 'good' + *phazein* 'speak'), attempted to apply it to the gods themselves; notably the Furies, who caused bad things to happen, by renaming them the *Eumenides*, or 'Gracious Ones', as chronicled [by Aeschylus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oresteia#The_Eumenides).

English is full of euphemisms; similar monosyllabic phonological euphemisms include *geez* (for *Jesus*), *(the) heck* (for [*(the) hell*](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/thehell.html)), *shoot* (for *shit*), *futz* (for *fuck*), etc. There are many other kinds, and there is a very thorough and fascinating discussion of the topic on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphemism) .

Comment: _[Futz](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/futz?region=us&q=FUTZ)_?

Comment: Incidentally, _gosh_ is one of the few words in my native dialect (DeKalb County, IL) that gets gratuitous rhoticization. That is, I speak the variety of Midwestern English that says "garsh", as well as "warsh" and "Warshington". Those are the only words that get it. For some reason, unknown to me; I'm a syntactician and semanticist, not a historical sociolinguist.

Answer (score 9):

The OED calls it a ‘mincing pronunciation of god’. The earliest citation is dated 1757.

Comment: Should we answer a GR?

Comment: @Kris I don't think it hurts.

Comment: @David In 'should', I meant as in  'what is our policy/ convention'.

Comment: @Kris, sounds like a question for the meta site.

Comment: I was asking my old friend Barrie England here in context.

Comment: @Kris: We've dealt with similar questions before. It's a matter of judgement as to the point at which a question becomes general reference. The answers to many of the questions here are available elsewhere to those who are prepared to take the trouble to find them.

Comment: And not everyone has a subscription to the OED.

Comment: @DavidWallace: the 'policy/convention' is mixed. There a couple of questions/discussions on meta already, maybe you and Kris want to add to them. The question here in particular doesn't seem to request more than what is already in some other easily accessible online dictionary (i.e. the OED is not necessary) and etymonline.

Comment: @BarrieEngland: Can you give any more specifics on the earliest citation?

Comment: @JLG: No, but anyone with a British public library card can get free access.

Comment: @Callithumpian: ‘Then there's highest—and lowest, by Gosh.’ From a play called ‘The Author – a comedy’ by one Samuel Foote.

Comment: Very few people living in the US have a British public library card.  I doubt that many people living in India or Australia or New Zealand or Canada or people studying English in countries in the Far East do either.

Comment: Going just on intuition, I'd connect it with the exclamation "land o' Goshen!" (see https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Land+o%27+Goshen!).