# Historically, did "Oh my Gosh" originate as an anti-God expression?

Tags: expressions, contemporary-english

There is a tendency in traditionally Christian societies (grossly speaking, the West) to leave behind words or expression which allude to such heritage or faith. A familiar example is CE and BCE instead of AD and BC. I'm interested here with the case of "Oh my Gosh", which is used instead of "Oh my God".

Now, according to [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/68360/192468), the first time this word was used as replacement for God was in the 16th century by [Nicholas Udall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicholas_Udall), who was himself a religious person (at one point he became a vicar, actually). So, although not in its origin, has the use of such word become as an expression of anti-theism? By anti-theism I mean the rejection of theism, not confined to but exemplified by atheism.

Comment: Possibly a good question for: 
 https://christianity.stackexchange.com

Comment: Some Christians I've known consider "oh my god" to be "taking the Lord's name in vain", which the bible prohibits. So you may find religious people using it for this reason. Also, as you point out, there are people who want to avoid referencing god at all, as a rejection of religion. I have no idea which are more common.

Comment: @AndyT I suspect there are more Christian English speakers than English speakers who choose to reject religion to the point of never saying /gad/. (lazy IPA)

Comment: Is there any evidence of _anyone_ who does this out of an anti-theistic persuasion? I've never met an atheist who avoids the G word on principle and I'd think this would be a very, very unusual view to take.

Comment: @tmgr No, I've never heard of an atheist avoiding the word "God" altogether, but certainly there are those who avoid expressions like "Oh my God" since it can be seen as implying a personal belief in God.

Comment: @jkej Indeed. That's where I'm coming from.

Comment: @jkej There must be some few people who avoid such expressions for the reasons you say (though I'd say it's incumbent on OP to at least attempt to prove their existence as part of the EL&U research requirement). In any case, they are _so very few_ that it would be a paranoid christian indeed who hears the bold march of secularism in the accommodatingly mild and mincing exclamation _Oh my gosh_.

Comment: @tmgr Yes, I agree that it's probably not very common for atheist to replace "Oh my good" with "Oh my gosh" if they want to avoid implying religious belief. It's much more likely that they would simply avoid the phrase altogether.

Comment: @jkej especially when there is such a wonderful wealth of profanity open to them

Comment: Is gosh not a contraction of "Land o' Goshen"?

Comment: @jkej atheists are unlikely to avoid the expression "Oh my God", because it's clearly just a meaningless expression of amazement. However, quite a few tend to replace "Thank God" to "Thank goodness", because the original phrase still retains genuine religious meaning.

Answer (score 77):

Quite the reverse. It's an example of a 'minced oath', where a similar-sounding word is substituted for the name of God in an expletive so as to avoid blasphemy. In 19th-century fiction, if a 'bad' character swore it would frequently be written as 'By G-d' or 'D-n you', as swearing was considered so offensive in polite society. Nowadays, I've noticed that some people use religious oaths meaninglessly without caring that they are offensive to believers.

Comment: _I've noticed that some people use religious oaths meaninglessly without caring that they are offensive to believers_ Many simply don't know that what they're saying causes offence, for them it's simply part of the patios they grew up speaking and would be bemused if told that their mode of expression is offensive to some.

Comment: There's a sea captain in the operetta *HMS Pinafore* (1878) who claims as a point of pride that he "never uses a big, big D".  Of course, he does say "damn" towards the end, and everyone is shocked.

Comment: "without caring that they are offensive to believers" They might not be offensive to believers any more though.

Comment: ["Look, I don't think it ought to be blasphemy, just saying 'Jehova'."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_hlMK7tCks)

Comment: @BinaryWorrier or *A*mused.

Comment: As a person who was raised Catholic, I can attest that this phrase comes from a place of respect for Christianity. One of the ten commandments is 'Do not take the Lord's name in vain', and stating "Oh my God!" would break that rule. 

Hence, we have such phrases as "Oh my Gosh", "Jiminy Christmas" and "Geeze Louise". Another early example is "Gazzooks!" which was originally "God's hooks" (a phrase that was hot in the middle ages).

Comment: I have seen, in published fiction, clearly-religious authors who use "gawd" in place of "God" presumably to avoid the whole blaspheming thing. It drives me bonkers. I'd much rather see "Oh my gosh" or my kids' generation's "OMG" (they say this out loud, pronounced "oh em gee") than the incredibly grating "Oh my gawd". Part of my annoyance might be because I'm not merged on cot/caught, so these words aren't homophones for me. It also somehow seems more disingenuous than the older minced oaths, like the difference between an old-fashioned radio bleep and the modern barely-disguised "sh-t".

Comment: @1006a *the modern barely-disguised "sh-t"*? In my country, most radio shows for people aged under 40 don't even bleep out the F word, while "shit" is regularly heard on prime-time public broadcast TV comedy shows. :-)

Comment: @Chappo That would be fine with me. It's not the words I object to, it's the hypocrisy of censoring them, but so lightly that no one is in any doubt of what's meant--even children who might not have heard the word before.

Comment: I'm an atheist, and in principle I would prefer to avoid using religious-based oaths, simply because they don't make sense given that I don't believe in any religion. However, having grown up in the culture I did, it's basically impossible to do. When I'm frustrated, I say things like, "Oh, Jesus, come on," simply because they're part of the linguistic environment that was programmed into me from an early age.