# What does ”gosh” mean?

Tags: semantics

I know a woman who is born again christian and she is very religious. She doesn’t like it when people say ”oh my God” and corrects them and instead says ”oh my *gosh*” .

But isn’t gosh the same thing as God?
So if you say ”oh my gosh” , you’re still saying the Lords name in vain?

Comment: Here is a related question on the [origin of the word](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68336/what-is-the-origin-of-gosh) .  As your question is framed, it sounds opinion-based.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minced_oath

Answer (score 2):

To a certain kind of religious mentality, "gosh" is a euphemism for God, just as "hades" is a euphemism for Hell.

> - [**euphemism**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/euphemism) - "a mild or pleasant word or phrase that is used instead of one that is unpleasant or offensive."

Once a euphemism, nowadays it's just an interjection.

> - [**gosh**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gosh) -  used as a mild oath or to express surprise.